# Xquery preserve spaces while tokenizing

Tags: xquery, tokenize

I am trying to achieve the below using XQuery
**Input**

```
<DemoXML>
This is a sample line one
this is line number two
this     line      contains     multiple      spaces
paragraph ends
</DemoXML
```

**Required Output(Two Records)**

```
<Record1>
This is a sample line one
this     line      contains     multiple      spaces
paragraph ends
</Record1>

<Record2>
This is a sample line one
this     line      contains     multiple      spaces
paragraph ends
</Record2>
```

I tried using Tokenize but the problem is tokenize function removes all the 'Spaces' in the secondline.
this is line number two

```
fn:tokenize($input,'\n')
```

**Tokenize Output**

```
This is a sample line one
this is line number two
this line contains multiple spaces
paragraph ends
```

Can someone let me know a workaround plz

Comment: How does your input look, how does the wanted output look? Which exact XQuery code using `tokenize` have you used respectively if you don't want to tokenize on white space on which characters do you want to tokenize?

Comment: Forgot to mention am tokenizing based on new line character '\n'. Input is the first block of code. When I tokenize using the new line character it removes the whitespaces which I need to preserve

Comment: If you tokenize the input with several lines on a newline why does the result have records? Shouldn't there be four? Can you please add the minimal XQuery code that produces the output you have shown? Also add information about the XQuery version you use/can use as perhaps the XQuery 3 analyze-string function gives more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Martin. Appreciate it.Here is the xquery function: fn:tokenize($input,'\n') which gave the output as the above Tokenizer output mentioned. We are using xquery 1.0 as there is no support for 3.0 so cannot use analyze-string

Comment: Which XQuery 1 processor do you use, how to do your parse the input? Are you sure it is the tokenize call that strips the blanks and not some other step? I can't reproduce the problem at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMey/0 with Saxon 9.

Comment: I am working on this using Oracle OSB. Looks like it might be some product issue. Will check with them as well

Comment: It turns out the issue is with the browser. In the backend the process is not trimming the values. Thanks for the help Martin.

Answer (score 2):

Your attached query is working fine. Also attached generated output for your reference. May be issue in processor which you are using. I test this query in Marklogic console and Oxygen Editor with XQuery 9.6.0.7

let $val1:=

This is a sample line one
this is line number two
this     line      contains     multiple      spaces
paragraph ends

return tokenize($val1,'\n')

Generate Output:
This is a sample line one this is line number two this     line      contains     multiple      spaces paragraph ends